# How can I make an even-odd command for my Discord.js bot?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I currently am making a discord bot. I'm trying to make a command that determines whether a number is even or odd, `evenodd`. However, my bot does not send anything when I send "$betterfly evenodd 'number'".

Here is my code:

```js
if (msg.content === '$betterfly evenodd') {
    if (msg.content.endsWith("0") || msg.content.endsWith("2") || msg.content.endsWith("4") || msg.content.endsWith("6") || msg.content.endsWith("8")) {
        msg.channel.send('Even');
    } else {
        msg.channel.send('Odd')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters use modulo '%' to get the remainder of the division by 2 if it's 0 then the number is even if that's not the case then it's odd.

The code above returns nothing because it checks whether the message that has been sent is equal to '$betterfly evenodd' or not and then checks again if it ends with numbers and it definitely doesn't so it doesn't return any messages.

Do this instead

```
client.on('message', message => {
 
    var div_list = message.content.split(" "); 
    if (div_list.length == 3) {
        if(div_list[0] == "$betterfly" && div_list[1] == 'evenodd')
        {
            var integer = parseInt(div_list[2], 10);
 
            if (integer % 2) {
                  message.channel.send('Odd');
            }
            else {
                  message.channel.send('Even');
            }
        } 
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, but now its spamming it rather than saying it once

Comment: @alexdev_ I have updated and tested the code, it should work properly now.